# Where can I find the Handover Protocol setting on the new Facebook Meta Business Suite?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

One of the pages I manage has been updated to the new UI and I could not find the setting anymore.

The setting can be found here before the UI update.
https://flow.ai/blog/handle-facebook-messenger-handovers

Answer (score 1):

It lives under the page settings on facebook.com not business.facebook.com (Meta Business Suite).

https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=advanced_messaging